# Apache freezes at a single PHP page

Tags: php, windows, apache

All my PHP pages work fine but there is one PHP page that used to work ok but now it freezes (when I go to it in the browser, it times out without a response).

This is the only error that's written to logs:

```
[Thu Nov 18 12:23:18 2010] [notice] Apache/2.2.15 (Win32) PHP/5.2.13 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Nov 18 12:23:18 2010] [notice] Server built: Mar  4 2010 11:27:46
[Thu Nov 18 12:23:18 2010] [notice] Parent: Created child process 3928
[Thu Nov 18 12:23:19 2010] [notice] Child 3928: Child process is running
[Thu Nov 18 12:23:19 2010] [notice] Child 3928: Acquired the start mutex.
[Thu Nov 18 12:23:19 2010] [notice] Child 3928: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Thu Nov 18 12:23:19 2010] [notice] Child 3928: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
[Thu Nov 18 12:23:59 2010] [notice] Parent: child process exited with status 255 -- Restarting.
[Thu Nov 18 12:24:05 2010] [notice] Apache/2.2.15 (Win32) PHP/5.2.13 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Nov 18 12:24:05 2010] [notice] Server built: Mar  4 2010 11:27:46
[Thu Nov 18 12:24:05 2010] [notice] Parent: Created child process 388
[Thu Nov 18 12:24:06 2010] [notice] Child 388: Child process is running
[Thu Nov 18 12:24:06 2010] [notice] Child 388: Acquired the start mutex.
[Thu Nov 18 12:24:06 2010] [notice] Child 388: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Thu Nov 18 12:24:06 2010] [notice] Child 388: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
[Thu Nov 18 12:24:24 2010] [notice] Parent: child process exited with status 255 -- Restarting.
[Thu Nov 18 12:24:25 2010] [notice] Apache/2.2.15 (Win32) PHP/5.2.13 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Nov 18 12:24:25 2010] [notice] Server built: Mar  4 2010 11:27:46
[Thu Nov 18 12:24:25 2010] [notice] Parent: Created child process 2816
[Thu Nov 18 12:24:26 2010] [notice] Child 2816: Child process is running
[Thu Nov 18 12:24:26 2010] [notice] Child 2816: Acquired the start mutex.
[Thu Nov 18 12:24:26 2010] [notice] Child 2816: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Thu Nov 18 12:24:26 2010] [notice] Child 2816: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
[Thu Nov 18 12:24:26 2010] [notice] Parent: child process exited with status 255 -- Restarting.
[Thu Nov 18 12:24:27 2010] [notice] Apache/2.2.15 (Win32) PHP/5.2.13 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Nov 18 12:24:27 2010] [notice] Server built: Mar  4 2010 11:27:46
[Thu Nov 18 12:24:27 2010] [notice] Parent: Created child process 3680
[Thu Nov 18 12:24:28 2010] [notice] Child 3680: Child process is running
[Thu Nov 18 12:24:28 2010] [notice] Child 3680: Acquired the start mutex.
[Thu Nov 18 12:24:28 2010] [notice] Child 3680: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Thu Nov 18 12:24:28 2010] [notice] Child 3680: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
[Thu Nov 18 12:28:52 2010] [notice] Parent: child process exited with status 255 -- Restarting.
[Thu Nov 18 12:28:53 2010] [notice] Apache/2.2.15 (Win32) PHP/5.2.13 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Nov 18 12:28:53 2010] [notice] Server built: Mar  4 2010 11:27:46
[Thu Nov 18 12:28:53 2010] [notice] Parent: Created child process 3828
[Thu Nov 18 12:28:54 2010] [notice] Child 3828: Child process is running
[Thu Nov 18 12:28:54 2010] [notice] Child 3828: Acquired the start mutex.
[Thu Nov 18 12:28:54 2010] [notice] Child 3828: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Thu Nov 18 12:28:54 2010] [notice] Child 3828: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
```

The only thing I have added to that page is some JavaScript code. I have also tried commenting out the whole content of the page just in case there is some endless recursion in the code.

I have restarted Apache and PC several times.

My OS is Windows 7. What could be a problem?

Comment: What happens when you remove the javascript code that you have added?

Comment: post the code for that page, infinite loop somewhere ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running the script through command line rather than through the server - this may give you a more specific error message in the console.  The error log you posted doesn't seem to show anything relating to your script as far as I can tell.

In Linux you would just type:

prompt> php myScript.php

I imagine that you can do the same from a command terminal in Windows?

Answer (score 1):

I think you could download non-thread-safe (nts) PHP binaries. They will not correctly work on Windows.